# Well-definedness of maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics

Consider a family $\{\mu_\theta:\theta\in\Theta\}$ of probability measures on a measurable space $X$. Given $x\in X$, the maximum likelihood estimate is the value of $\theta$ which maximizes the likelihood of $x$, i.e. which maximizes $\frac{d\mu_\theta}{d\nu}|_x$ for a measure $\nu$ on $X$ with $\mu_\theta\ll\nu$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

This is obviously not well-defined since $\frac{d\mu_\theta}{d\nu}$ is only an equivalence class of functions, up to a.e. equality.

In the texts I've seen (e.g. van der Vaart's *Asymptotic Statistics*) this doesn't seem to be addressed. What is the rigorous measure-theoretic formulation of maximum likelihood estimation, and is there a standard reference where it's explained?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer yo your question?

Comment: Exercise (which will not answer the question but which may help some people understand the nature of maximum-likelihood estimation): Show that the value of $\theta$ that maximizes $\left.\frac{d\mu_\theta}{d\nu}\right|_x$ does not depend on which measure is in the role of $\nu$ as long as $\mu_\theta\ll\nu$ for all values of $\theta. \qquad$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Indeed, the densities $f_\th:=d\mu_\th/d\nu$ are defined only $\nu$-a.e., and hence it makes no sense to define a maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) as a maximizer of $f_\th(x)$ in $\th$ for **arbitrary** versions of the densities.

Usually, though, it is assumed that versions $f_\th$ of the densities **can** be chosen so that the likelihood $L_x(\th):=f_\th(x)$ be regular enough in $\th$. In particular, in proofs of the [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Consistency) of the MLE, one of the standard assumptions is that the likelihood $L_x(\th)$ be continuous in $\th$; in proofs of [central limit theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency) for the MLE, one of the standard assumptions is that the likelihood $L_x(\th)$ be twice differentiable in $\th$.

In fact, usually it is a family $(f_\th)$ of densities (regular in $\th$ to some extent) that is assumed, whereas the family $(\mu_\th)$ with $d\mu_\th=f_\th\,d\nu$ may come next, if ever. Also, the choice of the reference measure $\nu$ usually matters little -- because, for any two mutually absolutely continuous reference measures, the likelihood profiles $\th\mapsto L_x(\th)$ will be proportional to each other (with the proportionality coefficient depending only on $x$), which usually will not affect statistical inference based on the likelihood.
So, the difficulty that concerns you hardly ever arises.

For some textbook statistical models (that is, for some families $(\mu_\th)$), it is impossible to make $L_x(\th)$ continuous in $\th$. E.g., for real $\th>0$, let $\mu_\th$ be the joint distribution of $n$ iid random variables each with the uniform distribution over the interval $[0,\th]$. Choosing the versions $f_\th$ of the densities of $\mu_\th$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure over $\R^n$) so that for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\R^n$ we have $f_\th(x)=\th^{-n}\,1(\max_i x_i\le\th)$, and so, the MLE is $\max_i x_i$. However, if we choose the versions $f_\th$ of the densities of $\mu_\th$ so that $f_\th(x)=\th^{-n}\,1(\max_i x_i<\th)$, then $L_x(\th)=f_\th(x)$ does not attain a maximum in $\th$ for any $x$, so that now an MLE will not exist, strictly speaking.
A generalized definition of an MLE is given in Section 2 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-11/issue-1/Optimal-order-uniform-and-nonuniform-bounds-on-the-rate-of/10.1214/17-EJS1264.full). With that definition, even for $f_\th(x)=\th^{-n}\,1(\max_i x_i<\th)$, $\max_i x_i$ will be the generalized MLE.